# Why can I assign a longer string to a pointer in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1);
    ptr = "Hello World";

    puts(ptr);
    getchar();
}
```

im not a malloc() expert but isn't that code supposed to give an error since i allocated only one byte but assigned a value that contains 11 bytes to *ptr pointer ?
or does the H get stored in the place i assigned and then the rest of the string just goes in the places after it ?

Comment: This is not your code or you would be getting an error, because `(char *) ptr` is not an lvalue.

Comment: If you actually wrote `ptr = "Hello World";`, then that's a pointer assignment; it doesn't copy the contents of any array. But please update your question to show the code you actually compiled (copy-and-paste it, don't re-type it).

Comment: Side note; `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1... and math tells us that anything multiplied by 1 results in the same value.  You have two levels of redundancy there.  Just use `malloc(1)`.

Answer (score 6):

You are reassigning the pointer 'ptr' to another block of memory, so you won't see any error.  However, the block of memory (size 1) that you allocated is "lost" and leads to a memory leak.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  If you want to see the anticipated error, try to use `memcpy(ptr, "Hello World")` which will attempt to write the 11 bytes to the memory allocated to ptr.

Comment: @austin: That would be UB. You won't necessarily get an error.

Answer (score 1):

When using `malloc` you're requesting some memory and `malloc` returns the first address of that memory (if it can be given). When you re-assign the pointer you're not doing anything with the memory it points to. You just change *what* the pointer points to.

What you're doing here is technically valid C **but** you're creating a memory leak because you lose the address of the `malloc`ed memory, which you must `free` when you're done with it.